# Dropdownlist selected value is not working for binding data

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` on selection of which i bind the other `dropdownlist`

In first dropdownlist,

If *I select a value, some data should bind to the second dropdownlist. If I select second value them some other data should bind.*

Here is my code which I tried so far

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {   
        BindAdjustmentType();
        if (ddlAdjustmentType.SelectedValue == "9")
        {
            BindItemCode("select distinct REPLACE(Current_Item_Code  + ' '  + QUOTENAME(Current_Item_Desc,'()'), '*','') as ItemCode, " +
                          "Current_Item_Code from WMS_Storage_Bin where status='Confirmed'");
        }
        if (ddlAdjustmentType.SelectedValue == "10")
        {
            BindItemCodeaddStock("select distinct (Navision_Item_Id + ' ' + QUOTENAME(Item_short_desc, '()')) as AddStock, " +
                                  "Navision_Item_Id from Item_mst");
        }            
    }
}
```

Also see my dropdown aspx code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdjustmentType" runat="server" Style="width: 165px" CssClass="xy8">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">--- Select ---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I tried putting the debug point, but it was not hitting the code

**UPDATED**

```
public void BindItemCode(string query)
{
    DataTable dtitemcode = CF.ExecuteDT(query);
    ddlItemCode.DataTextField = "ItemCode";
    ddlItemCode.DataValueField = "Current_Item_Code";
    ddlItemCode.DataSource = dtitemcode;
    ddlItemCode.DataBind();
    ddlItemCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}

public void BindItemCodeaddStock(string query)
{
    DataTable dtadditemcode = CF.ExecuteDT(query);
    ddlItemCode.DataTextField = "AddStock";
    ddlItemCode.DataValueField = "Navision_Item_Id";
    ddlItemCode.DataSource = dtadditemcode;
    ddlItemCode.DataBind();
    ddlItemCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```

At the same time i have written in `Jquery` for that dropdownlist too for other functionalities.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ew65qt6/) it is

Comment: Your DropDownList `ddlAdjustmentType` did not have the 9 or 10 values, where do you bind them and how ? maybe there is the issue

Comment: @Aristos: I inspected that value, It **does** has `9` and `10` Also see my updated question that how i bind them.

Comment: @RahulSingh: I am binding it inside `(!IsPostBack)`

Comment: @RahulSingh: earlier that was simple on pageload only one dropdown has to be binded. But now I added one more value to the dropdown so that the next dropdown should be binded on the basis of selection from first dropdown. I havent added any other `postback`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95778/discussion-between-coder-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: Just a moment, the `if (!IsPostBack)` is means that you do not have any post back, so you do not have any selected value !

Comment: @Aristos: so how to get selected value with `if (!IsPostback)`
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is you are binding the dropdown `ddlAdjustmentType` on the intial get request. Now when user makes any selection since the autopostback property of `ddlAdjustmentType` is not set nothing happens. Even if you set that property it won't work because you wrote your code inside:-

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   //Bind dropdown etc.  
}
```

You will have to add a Change event in dropdown and either ask the user to click the button or if you want the other dropwdown to be populated as soon as you select something, set the `AutoPostBack` property of dropdown to true:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdjustmentType" runat="server" autopostback="true"
     onselectedindexchanged="ddlAdjustmentType_change" Style="width: 165px" ..
```

Then in code behind write the event method:-

```
protected void Student_type_dd_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (ddlAdjustmentType.SelectedValue == "9")
    {
        ..logic here
    }
    if (ddlAdjustmentType.SelectedValue == "10")
    {
        ...logic here
    }  
}
```

But IMHO if you are using jquery ajax already don't unnecassily do a postback, write a `change` event of `ddlAdjustmentType` and then make a ajax call and populate other dropdowns.

Comment: sir, can we do that without `postback` ?

Comment: @coder - Yes absolutely, read my last point. Add a change event in jquery code, make a ajax call get data and bind other dropdowns.